# Notification center values is not getting update for first, second time

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have an `pagMenuController` on did select method I am passing the index. And in another `vc` I am getting that `index` values and I needs to show the view respective with incoming `index` value.

**Code in my FirstVC:**

```
func pageMenuController(_ pageMenuController: PageMenuController, didSelectMenuItem index: Int, direction: PageMenuNavigationDirection) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateView"), object: nil, userInfo: ["indexValue": index]) 
}
```

**Code in my SecondVC:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:  #selector(ContViewController.incomingNotification(_:)), name:  NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateView"), object: nil)
}

@objc func incomingNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let indexVal = notification.userInfo?["indexValue"] as? Int {
        print(indexVal)
    }
}
```

When ever my screen appears, I needs to get the `index` values. But when I click on my menu items first, second time `index` values in not showing. 3rd, and above time its coming. what I have missed.

Any solutions?

Thank you

Comment: try this `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { super.viewWillAppear(animated)`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  i tried. Getting same first time not showing. But this time above 2nd times its showing the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move your observer to viewdidload

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:  #selector(ContViewController.incomingNotification(_:)), name:  NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateView"), object: nil)
 }
```

Comment: Any help on here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071086/showing-the-selected-data-id-values-at-first-in-collection-view